# What does Micrometer `@Timed` monitor?

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, metrics, newrelic, micrometer

I have used New Relic micrometer registry for monitoring metrics in my Spring boot application. I used `@Timed` annotation at the controller level to monitor each API separately. However, I am unable to make sense of the data that I am getting through this. I am getting 5 metrics through this which are `Average`, `Count`, `Sum`, `Max` and `Min`. It is difficult to find out what these values represent as there is no unit on the Y axis. I assume `count` is giving me the throughput of the API. Is `average` giving me the response time? If not, how do I get that for my APIs? Reference code:

```
@Timed(percentiles = {0.95, 0.99, 0.50}, value = "company-fetch-id")
```

Reference image:

[image]